# # Active record validations : : How to validate date attributes in Rails(custom_validations)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

I have two models...

***models/Resident.rb*** : has_many: leaves

***models/leave.rb***: belongs_to: resident

Now  what I want to validate  leave model attributes before they get created..

***leave.rb*** attributes : **start_date,end_date,destination**

***here is my leave model***:

```
class Leave < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resident
  validates :destination,presence:true
  validates :end_date,presence: true
  validates :start_date,presence: true
  before_create :check_correct_leave

  private

  def check_correct_leave

   if resident.hostel.hostel=='J'
     (self.end_date - self.start_date).to_i == 4 ||  (self.end_date - self.start_date).to_i == 5

   else
     errors.add(:start_date, "Leave are granted only 4 or 5 days")
   end

  end

end
```

I want **check_correct_leave** method to also check  --> if  the resident  already  have a leave (stored in a leave model) of that a month (month means jan,feb,etc) then it should generate  an error that:

**"You can't mark leave cause you have already marked leave for this month"**
and  model should not store that leave.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another validation method like this

```
validate :check_leaves_in_same_month


def check_leaves_in_same_month  
   if self.resident.leaves.where('start_date > ?', self.start_date.beginning_of_month).any? 
       errors.add("You can't mark leave cause you have already marked leave for this month")
   end
end
```

Comment: it is working but Im getting flash error from my controller :
`def create
    @leave=current_user.resident.leaves.create(leave_params)
    if @leave.save
      flash[:info] = "Leave successfully marked"
      redirect_to leaves_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Mark Your Leave Again (Not  a vaild Leave) !"
      redirect_to new_leave_path
    end
  end`


**flash[:danger] = "Mark Your Leave Again (Not  a vaild Leave) !"** this one error ..

Comment: if you want to show the error message added, you can change flash[:danger] to `flash[:danger]= @leave.errors.full_messages.first`

Comment: yeah that's working but when I am creating a leave it is showing me  error -->
 **You can't mark leave cause you have already marked leave for this month**
but the leave is getting stored in database !! how to fix it ?

Comment: ah ok, you need to change `current_user.resident.leaves.create(leave_params)` to `current_user.resident.leaves.new(leave_params)` because the leave created can't be saved twice since it  has already start_date in the same month

Comment: But **before_create**  will not work? and if I am changing  it to **validates**
then it is saving leaves with any date difference not by the function made by me: **check_correct_leave**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108513/discussion-between-abdoo-dev-and-nischay-namdev).

Answer (score 0):

```
def has_leave_for_the_same_month?
  resident.leaves.any? do |other_leave|
    other_leave.start_date.month == leave.start_date.month
  end
end

errors.add(...) if has_leave_for_the_same_month?
```

Comment: You should use any? block